# Java 11 requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater with Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, ubuntu, gradle

When I run ````cordova run android``` in the path of my project I get

```
Android Studio project detected
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /path/to/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /path/to/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/norsan-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

My version of Java

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.119.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.119.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My version of javac

```
$ javac --version
javac 11.0.5
```

My version of Cordova

```
$ cordova --version
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

My version of Node

```
$ node --version
v10.15.2
```

My version of Nodejs

```
$ nodejs --version
v10.15.2
```

My version of NPM

```
$ npm --version
5.8.0
```

My version of Gradle

```
$ gradle -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/java/groovy-all.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.16
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on March 28 2019
JVM:          11.0.5 (Private Build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.119.04)
OS:           Linux 5.0.0-38-generic amd64
```

I found that `android-studio --version` didn't do anything but silently wait, but when I open the program through the graphical user interface I see that the version is 3.6.1.

My version of androidsdk is Unknown... Not sure why.

```
$ androidsdk --version
SDK_ROOT=/home/galen/snap/androidsdk/21/AndroidSDK
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/galen/snap/androidsdk/21
Unknown version
```

My version of Ubuntu

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=disco
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.04 (Disco Dingo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.04"
VERSION_ID="19.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=disco
UBUNTU_CODENAME=disco
```

My understanding is that Java 11 comes later than JDK 1.8, so why does the requirements check fail? And, how do I fix this requirements check failure?

Comment: Java 9 was a **major** release of Java that introduced a new module system, and removed several deprecated classes, methods and features. Use Java 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update:*

Java 11 [is supported for cordova 10+](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk) which allows for the same minimum Android versions as cordova 9. This should now be the preferred solution.

---

*Original answer (for reference):*

You are correct that Java 11 is more recent than JDK 1.8 and that it *should* work in theory.

However, [cordova explicitly requires JDK 1.8](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/908) still:

> Android doesn’t use oracles java but their own implementation, which at the moment is like java 8. So this is an android limitation, not something cordova can fix.

(cf. also [issue 510](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/510))

Their development guide [explicitly mentions JDK 1.8](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk) as well:

> **Java Development Kit (JDK)**
>
> Install Java Development Kit (JDK) 8.

So the fix for now would be installing JDK 1.8 (if you go for Oracle note their recently changed license terms). You may watch [PR 928](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/928) that attempts to ease that restriction, though.

Comment: I'm still getting errors trying to use ```cordova run android```, but they are related to a different issue. I've accepted your answer believing that it resolved the dependancy issue I was having. Note that I used G Alternative to manager having multiple versions of Java JRE/JDK.

Comment: When reverting to JDK 1.8, I stop getting the above "requirement" error, but then I get another instead: "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8." -- So PLEASE how to resolve this conflict??

Comment: Their (linked) development guide mentions that _"you can install Java Development Kit (JDK) 11 if using cordova-android version 10+."_ (which is their current version).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the command does not respect JAVA_HOME variable (you need to set this to Java 8 as well)

As someone already mentioned, the bump from 8 to 11 is massive. Many libraries that were in Java 8 are moved out in Java 11, so while Java itself is backward compatible, the included libraries are not.

What works for me is to set JAVA_HOME to JDK8

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

**AND** I need to configure system wide java and javac settings with commands

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: Can we use **openjdk 11** for Android Studio projects?